# Display placemarks in only 1 specific folder

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, kml

I want to show only placemarks from only 1 folder on click first control, second folder = second control. Second question, that google api works with styles only, when they outside folder tag

My KML looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>

<Folder id="Fusiontables1">
<name>Fusiontables folder1</name>
<Style id="cameraIcon1">
<BalloonStyle>
<text>$[description]</text>
</BalloonStyle>
<IconStyle>
<Icon>
<href>http://www.google.com/help/hc/images/maps_camera.png</href>
</Icon>
</IconStyle>
</Style>
<Placemark>
<name><![CDATA[Sydney]]></name>
<styleUrl>#cameraIcon</styleUrl>
<description>
<![CDATA[<br><b>Name</b>: Sydney<br><b>Location</b>: -33.936293,151.165388]]>
</description>
<Point>
<coordinates>
151.165388,-33.936293,0
</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
</Folder>

<Folder id="Fusiontables2">
<name>Fusiontables folder2</name>
<Style id="cameraIcon2">
<BalloonStyle>
<text>$[description]</text>
</BalloonStyle>
<IconStyle>
<Icon>
<href>http://www.google.com/help/hc/images/maps_camera.png</href>
</Icon>
</IconStyle>
</Style>
<Placemark>
<name><![CDATA[Bondi beach]]></name>
<styleUrl>#cameraIcon2</styleUrl>
<description>
<![CDATA[<br><b>Name</b>: Bondi beach<br><b>Location</b>: -33.891813,151.273160]]>
</description>
<Point>
<coordinates>
151.27316,-33.891813,0
</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

and this js shows ALL placemarks, but i need only one

```
kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl, {
                        preserveViewport: true,
                        suppressInfoWindows: false
                    });
```

**UPD.** geoxml library solves the problem

Comment: Is there a question? Or just complaints?

Comment: question is: how to display placemarks in only 1 specific folder

Comment: Please update your question to make that more obvious.  Have you investigated any of the third party KML parsers ([like geoxml-v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml-v3_KmlFolders.html))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not available using the Google Maps Javascript API v3 KmlLayer, you can do that using the third party parser [geoxml-v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml-v3_KmlFolders.html).